# Are there any restriction on the number of ejabberd nodes?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Using ejabberd configuration i am able to test around 40000 clients to use a single vm and also able to do clustering with 2 machines. I am aware that this is a low number and much more connections can be handled by a single vm by fine tuning. The requirement is to support 1 million connections which means it requires 25 nodes. Is it possible to have 25 nodes on a ejabberd setup ?

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience, but there are some users (from way back) claiming that there's a full mesh limit of 50-100, so 40 should still be possible (http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-February/064294.html).

From my own perspective, I would suggest to see the cost implications of these vs. vertically scaling the host machine to support more connections. If the cost is almost equal or less to vertically scale, and your traffic requirement is definitely 1M concurrent, then it makes sense to have a bigger machine setup. Clustering makes more sense on scaling while your user base is growing, so you don't incur downtime.

Comment: I confirm it is possible to have a 25 nodes ejabberd cluster.